# check form validation on jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm  using form validation jquery. And form input like this

```
<form id="form-valid">
 <select id="country" name="country" class="input-group form-control input-sm">
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="America">America</option>
    <option value="Eropa">Eropa</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" id="codetax" name="codetax"><input>
 <select id="status" name="status" class="input-group form-control input-sm">
    <option value="small">samll island</option>
    <option value="big">big island</option>
    <option value="medium">medium island</option>
 </select>
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-sm btn-form-filter form-control"    data-target="tmppo" id="btnsave" type="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

But my problem is, i need to check if country are Asia, taxcode and status must filled. But if country not Asia, taxcode and status can be empty. How do i did that when i'm using submit button?? I'm still new about jquery form validate. Pls help me.

Update ok it's works now, i do this on my from validate using depends

```
$('#form').validate({
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            rules: {
                country: {
                    required: true
                },
                taxcode: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                            if ($('#country').val() == 'Asia') {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
             messages: {
                codetax : "Pleasa instert taxcode
            },
        });
```

And on code html i have to use "name" to get rules. For all tq for helping me :)

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the built-in method supplied by the `validate` library via `.addMethod()` found on the [documentation site](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/). I modified your form to better conform.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add the method here, you can modify the code inside as need be
    $.validator.addMethod("country", function(value, element) {
        if(value == 'Asia') {
            var getCodeTax  =   $('input[name=codetax]').val();
            if(getCodeTax === '') {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }, 'You must select tax code');

    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            status:"required",
            // This applies the country method above to the country dropdown
            country: "country"
        },
        messages: {
        }
    });
});
</script>
<form id="form-valid" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
 <select name="country" id="country" class="input-group form-control input-sm">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="America">America</option>
    <option value="Eropa">Eropa</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" id="codetax" name="codetax" />
 <select id="status" name="status" class="input-group form-control input-sm">
    <option value="small">samll island</option>
    <option value="big">big island</option>
    <option value="medium">medium island</option>
 </select>
 <input class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-sm btn-form-filter form-control"  value="save"  data-target="tmppo" id="btnsave" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I believe you can do a function `rules: { country: function(){ if...` but I think the preferred method according to the documentation is adding a method

Comment: hey i just try like u said on $('form').validate({ rules:, but i'm not using condition funvtion if, but i use depends. I'm edit my question, is work. Tq for helping me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You create a function to check what type of country selected on button click event

```
$( "btnsave" ).click(function() {
  var country = $("country").val();

  if (country == 'Asia')
  {
    //show required message here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change type of the button to submit.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form-valid' function(e){
var country = $("#country").val();
if(country == 'Asia'){
   if($('#codetax').val()=="" || $('#status').val()==""){
      e.preventDefault();
      //now form won't submit. Still need to add error messages.
      }
   }
});
```

If you don't want to change the type of button to submit then :

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnsave' function(e){
var country = $("#country").val();
if(country == 'Asia'){
   if($('#codetax').val()!="" && $('#status').val()!=""){
      $('#form-valid').submit();
   }
   else{
      //add your error messages
   }
}
});
```

Comment: Well is seems work for me, but my question is how to use on $('#form').validate???